# Enable multicast on dummy interface on startup

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, linux-networking, multicast

I have a dummy interface on a Centos 6.3 machine which I would like to use for multicast traffic. The problem is it does not come up with the MULTICAST option by default; I need to manually add it with *ifconfig dummy0 multicast*.

Is it possible to configure the interface to start with multicast enabled? I haven't been able to find any configuration options that do that, and experimenting with adding things like *MULTICAST=yes* to */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-dummy0* have not been successful. Is there a configuration option I am missing, or am I going to need to put the ifconfig command in an init script?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through /etc/sysconfig/network-functions, there is no "MULTICAST" option for the interface config scripts.

By default your interface SHOULD support multicast traffic. It may be that your network does not support multicast. Where I work, we have to enable multicast on our VLANs at the switch layer.

Comment: I think the issue is that it is a dummy interface. The real interfaces all come up with multicast enabled. If I manually enable multicast on the dummy interface it is usable for multicast traffic, although as a dummy interface there is no switch to be concerned with.